# Dropdown from a package to display the Country and State

Tags: laravel, github, package, state, country

Hi I want to display a dropdown of country and state from a package.I stucked in to display it in my blade.Anyone would like to help me ?

```
                        <div class="form-group pmd-textfield pmd-textfield-floating-label ">
                            <label>Country</label>
                            <select name= "" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Select Country</option>  
                                @foreach ($country as $country)

                                 <option>{{$country}}</option>  

                                @endforeach   
                            </select><span class="pmd-textfield-focused"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group pmd-textfield pmd-textfield-floating-label ">
                            <label for="type_id">State</label>
                            <select name= "state" id="stateId" class="states order-alpha form-control">
                                <option value="">Select State</option>       

                            </select><span class="pmd-textfield-focused"></span>
                        </div>
```

```
controller
 public function create()
    {


        $countries = Countries::where('geo.subregion', "South-Eastern Asia");
        $country = $countries->pluck('name.common');
        $state = $countries->where('cca2', $state)->first()->hydrateStates()->states->pluck('name');
        return view('job.create', compact('country'));
    }


The country show all the countries name through pluck.Now i need to have drop down for my state which need to be dependent on the country name.How shall i do that ?
```

Comment: this code not working? maybe is de foreach, you need change name of your variables, foreach(country as countries), your code in foreach is wrong

Comment: hi. Yes i did some changes. I want my state dropdown need to be connected with the cou try drop down .. how cann i solve that ? now i can only display the country name through pluck

Comment: i have edit my codes for current prob. https://github.com/antonioribeiro/countries i am using this package